# Get URL of Views 'file' field

Tags: views, files

How can I get just the url of the uploaded file from the Views module 'file' field.  If I do the following:

```
print $view->render_field('field_url', $id);
```

I get the entire 'file' object in html format. How can I retrieve just the url of the uploaded file?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Image URL Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module you can set the field to 'Image URL' format and call it with

```
$fields["field_name"]->content
```

and it should only output the url to the image without any surrounding html

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm referring to the 'file' field which is different than the 'image' field